# Leave gap for header who is behind the content

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to make a Webpage with a banner so that when you scroll the content comes from the bottom and keeps sticking right under the upper half of the banner.

I immediately came up with the easy and ugly idea, that the content-box would have the size of the screen, a big `margin-top` and `overflow-y: scrolling`, but as I said...it would be the ugly way.

Thus my main problem is to achieve this and still have one single scroll-bar. I think the header has to be `position: fixed`...has anyone an css / more mobile friendly idea?
[image]

**EDIT:**

As requested a JSFiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/r2gbyjcs/

Comment: Could you add some code or a jsfiddle so we'll have something to work with?

Comment: If you have JQuery, you could use a JQuery Animation

Comment: @HéctorE http://jsfiddle.net/r2gbyjcs/

Comment: @DaemonOfTheWest What do you mean?

Comment: I just posted an answer, doesn't involve Javascript, all CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Before we begin**

Note that there is no such thing as "fancy" or "unfancy" in coding. In fact, if I were to define "fancy", I'd describe it as "unnecessary." Because if all you want is to achieve the same result but put in a rube goldberg amount of effort, that's just wasting your time. Your goal is to create the fastest and smoothest implementation, not put fancy code behind the veil.

**Solution**

The solution is to divide the header into 2 divs: Top and Bottom. Make them have same background to be indistinguishable, but make the top have `z-index: 0` while the bottom has `z-index: -1`. Then, split the height between the top and bottom and then adjust the `margin-top` of the content.

**HTML:**

```
<header>
    <div id="top">Hotel</div>
    <div id="bottom">Bottom half</div>
</header>
<div id="content">
    <h1>Best Shawarma in the world!</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <h1>Best Shawarma in the world!</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <h1>Best Shawarma in the world!</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <h1>Best Shawarma in the world!</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <h1>Best Shawarma in the world!</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <h1>Best Shawarma in the world!</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
header #top{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #fb3f26;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    right: 0px;
}
#content {
    background-color: #e0ecf3;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 200px;
}

header #bottom{
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #fb3f26;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/r2gbyjcs/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You could make the header `position:absolute` so it is fixed in place and taken out of the layout flow. Then add `padding-top` to the content box to compensate for the height of the header.

Comment: I think the header has to be `position: fixed` and i can't just set the padding because when you would scroll it just would be "overscrolled" some pixels later.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this, but it's not the fanciest way:

HTML

```
 <header id="header1">
    <div>Hotel</div>
</header>
<header id="header2">

</header>
    <div id="content">
    ...
```

CSS

```
#header1 {
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #fb3f26;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#header2 {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #fb3f26;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    min-height: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an easy way would be to just use `position:fixed` for the header/banner. Then edit the `z-index` so the banner is behind the content box and the header is above the content box. You can use `margin-top` to offset the height of the header/banner.

http://jsfiddle.net/haydensmack/r2gbyjcs/6/